# Using a case expression inside a Default/Expression on a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, datatable, default-value

I want to set an case clause inside the Default/Expression on a MySQL table. But I think i can explain better in an image, so look below please.

[image: The image is this one]

Currently i have the case expression that i want to use in a view. However i decided i want to have the result of that case expression stored inside of a table. 
I know i can have expressions like in column c that is the multiplication of column a * column b. 
I pretend to achive something like that but instead of the multiplication having the case clause, but when i put the case clause in the default expression i get this error: 
"ERROR 1067: Invalid default value for 'ciclo'" beeing 'ciclo' the name of my column

Answer (score 0):

Default value is a constant, if an expression is given, it will be evaluated at the time of the `CREATE TABLE`/`ALTER TABLE` command.

What you need is more likely a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
CREATE TABLE .... (
  ....
  ciclo VARCHAR(45) AS (CASE .... THEN 'invalido' ELSE .... END)
);
```